# What is the difference between these two types of value assign in C++ pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the difference of these two ways of variable value assignment ?

```
int x = 100;
int *valuePtr = &x;
*valuePtr = 20;
```

Why cannot I use `int *valuePtr = x;` this way ?

I will give a compile error. But after `int *valuePtr = &x;` and then `*valuePtr = 20;` will not give compile error.

Can anyone explain this ?

Comment: recommended to read about pointers: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: Because there is a difference between what something is and where something is. For instance, you are not your home address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = 100;
```

This declares an `int` variable called `x` and initializes it to 100.

```
int *valuePtr = &x;
```

This declares a pointer-to-`int` variable called `valuePtr` and initializes it with the address of `x` (`&` is the address-of operator).

```
*valuePtr = 20;
```

The expression `*valuePtr` *dereferences* the pointer and obtains a reference to its target -- the `int` object at its address.  So the whole expression assigns 20 to the *pointed-to* `int` object.

> Why I cannot use `int *valuePtr = x;` this way?

In this context, this is not allowed because `x` is not an `int *` (pointer-to-`int`), it is an `int`.  It's the same reason you can't say `std::string foo = 10;` -- the types are not compatible, and there is no implicit conversion between them.

Here's the summary:

- `x` has type `int`.
- `&x` has type `int *` and evaluates as the address of `x`.
- `int` is not implicitly convertible to `int *`, so `int *valuePtr = x;` does not compile.
- `valuePtr` has type `int *` so you can store `&x` in it (the types match).
- `*valuePtr` has type `int &` referring to the pointed-to `int`, so it can be assigned a new value through the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a pointer is just a variable that holds the address of something else. It's basically a sign saying "the thing you want is over *there*". `int *valuePtr = &x;` updates the sign so it points to `x`. `*valuePtr = 20;` *follows* the sign and tries to store `20` at the location the sign points to. `*int valuePtr = x;` is invalid syntax, it doesn't mean anything. If you meant `int *valuePtr = x;` then that fails since `x` is an integer which is not a pointer, so you cannot assign it to one (type mismatch).